# Appwrite JWT problem with new Appwrite cloud

Tags: cloud, appwrite

please, i will really appreciate your help. I had Appwrite application and i was able to find _APP_OPENSSL_KEY_V1 for JWT authentication in my API. But now, i got into Appwrite beta cloud and i have no idea how to find out what _APP_OPENSSL_KEY_V1 does my Appwrite application use. I know that I can use sdk-client-setJWT but if i do this, i do not have an attitute to all document, because of permissions.

I expect, that i will be able to know what _APP_OPENSSL_KEY_V1 does my Appwrite application use. I want to use it to verify user over jsonwebtoken in my API.

Answer (score 1):

You really aren't supposed to be using `_APP_OPENSSL_KEY_V1` with any of our APIs. This is, in fact extremely dangerous, and you really shouldn't be exposing your key in a client application.

Which SDK are you using, and what are you trying to accomplish?